# Transparent Overlay

Tags: vb.net, overlay

I'm trying to make an application which can overlay my screen with a transparent image in the middle. My goal is to make a crosshair for a game with no crosshair. My thinking is to detect if the active window title matches the game name, and if so display the overlaying crosshair. How would i make a screen overlay? This is my current code:

```
Private Function GetCaption() As String
    Dim Caption As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
    Dim hWnd As IntPtr = GetForegroundWindow()
    GetWindowText(hWnd, Caption, Caption.Capacity)
    Return Caption.ToString()
End Function

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If GetCaption() = "Game NameOf" Then
        'Display Crosshair
    End If 
End sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This methods works for most games but only in **windowmode!**

1. Place a picturebox on your Form and maximize yout picturebox
2. Disable your Windowboarders:

   `Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None`
3. Set your transperency key to black. Th

   `Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Black`
4. Set background color to black:

   `Me.PictureBox1.BackColor = Color.Black`
5. Set your window to foreground:

   `Me.TopMost = true`
6. Maximize your window:

   `Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized`

Now you can draw on your Picturebox in a Timer1_Tick or Form1_Paint event. Everything that is not Black will be drawn to your Desktop.

```
Dim g As = GraphicsPictureBox1.CreateGraphics
...
g.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 10, 10, 200, 200)
```

**Important:**

To pass input from mouse and keyboard through your window, your have to add the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` flag while .net creates your form. This can be done by [overriding `CreateParams` proterty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/system.windows.forms.control.createparams%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Australia%20%28English%29):

```
Const  WS_EX_TRANSPARENT As Long = &H20
...
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property  CreateParams() As System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams
Get 
    Dim  SecPerm As New SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode)
    SecPerm.Demand()
    Dim  cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
    cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT
    Return cp
End Get
End Property
```

Hope I could help you.

[image]

Comment: Hej Al-aex! Thank you so much! The WS_EX_TRANSPARENT did the job! I skipped the picture box, and went with a simple '+' symbol in a label as the scope.